# Iterable interface implementation

Tags: java, interface, iterator, stack

Can someone tell me if my implementation for Stack is right?

```
   class LevelIter<Node> implements Iterable<Node> {
        Stack<Node> s = null;
        public LevelIter(Stack<Node> s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
        public Iterator<Node> iterator(){
            Iterator<Node> it = new Iterator<Node>() {
                private int index = 0;

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext(){
                        return (index < s.size() && !s.isEmpty());
                }

                @Override
                public Integer next(){
                    return (Integer) (s.pop()).data;
                }

                @Override
                public void remove(){
                    s.remove();
                }
            };
            return it;
        }
    }
```

Where Node is a node in a binary tree -

```
  class Node{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    public Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
```

And I am calling in the main as --

```
    LevelIter<Node> l = new LevelIter<Node>(s);
    for(int n:l){
        System.out.println(n);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iterator probably shouldn't modify a shared data structure.  Your constructor should copy the passed stack so it doesn't pop elements from it.

Pass by reference and pass by value are tricky subjects to master.  You're actually copying the reference in your code, so the LevelIter's Stack object is going to be the same as whatever stack is passed in.  This means when you iterate using a LevelIter, its going to empty whatever stack LevelIter was constructed with.  This is probably undesirable and is the reason I suggest the following:

```
class LevelIter<Node> implements Iterable<Node> {
    Stack<Node> s = null;
    public LevelIter(Stack<Node> s) {
        this.s = (Stack)s.clone();
    }
    //rest is the same.
}
```

The rest of your code looks fine to me.  Best way to make sure your code works is to test it though.  Create a class which just tests this iterator.  Make sure its functioning the way you expect.

Comment: Yes but the reference is the same.  Objects in java are passed by reference, not by value.

Comment: ok .. I have another question.. Can I place this LevelIter class inside another class? because I tried that and I am getting this error -- "ReverseLevelOrder.java:20: error: <anonymous ReverseLevelOrder$LevelIter$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method next() in Iterator  Iterator<Node> it = new Iterator<Node>() {  where Node is a type-variable:  Node extends Object declared in class ReverseLevelOrder.LevelIter"

Comment: Nesting classes is allowed though I dislike it personally. Your error is happening because you've declared a return type of Integer for your next() method.  The return type must be Node, not interger because you are implementing a Iterator using the generic <Node>.  So either return node, or use an Integer generic instead like, Iterator<Integer> it = new Iterator<Integer>()

Comment: Ok.. thanks that fixed a few errors .. :) .. One last question .. I am confused between the implementation of "next()" and "remove()" In my case both do the same operation right i.e. s.pop()?

Comment: Remove is an optional operation. I would not implement it here if you do plan to copy the stack in your constructor.  If you don't copy the stack in your constructor, implement remove and yes, have it just do a pop.